# ImageProperties.SaveImagePropertiesAsync() doesn't save changes

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to save some properties into an image file in a Windows 10 UWP application, on the mobile phone.

```
var fileProperties = await file.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();

fileProperties.Rating = 25;
fileProperties.Title = "Title";
fileProperties.DateTaken = DateTime.Now;

await file.Properties.SavePropertiesAsync();
```

For some reason, the properties are not saved.

The file is created beforehand like this:

```
var file = await _sourceFolder.CreateFileAsync(pathToFile, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await bitmap.SaveToStorageFile(file);
```

where bitmap is of type WriteableBitmap.
The image is saved to a file, but the properties are not.

Does anyone know what I'm not doing correctly? There is no exception, no message about why it doesn't succceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the `StorageFile.Properties.SavePropertiesAsync`, which get the StorageItemContentProperties. And it use the original data to save to the file.

You should be able to use the `ImageProperties.SavePropertiesAsync` method. It use new ImageProperties data to save to the file.

For example:

```
var fileProperties = await file.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
fileProperties.Rating = 25;
fileProperties.Title = "title";
fileProperties.DateTaken = DateTime.Now;
await fileProperties.SavePropertiesAsync();
```

Comment: Oh, my bad, then... Thanks for the help. Marking your answer as the one. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that when rating is set to 0, other values (like Title) are not saved and no error is thrown